# Unable to open PST recovered from formatted HDD

Tags: hard-drive, microsoft-outlook, data-recovery, pst

I'm trying to recover a pst from a formatted HDD using EaseUs as the recovering software. 
I do manage to recover the file named outlook.pst however it seems to be split into several other files; outlook_000.pst, outlook_001.pst, etc. Explained further in the image [image]

Since it's split into several other files, I'm unable to open the pst file in outlook as I get an error that outlook.pst is not an outlook data file.

Please help me solve this as I need the e-mails back.

Many thanks in advance,
J

Comment: The file was fragmented, based on the information, not gully recovered do your options are to recover from a backup because your file isn't complete

Comment: None of those files have been modified in over a year

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys. Is there anyway which you can explain to me how I can recreate the PST file in order to access my emails please ?

Comment: You can't recreate a file if you don't have all the fragments of the file.  The file by the looks of it is only partially recovered.

Comment: Thanks for your replay Ramhound. How can I tell if all the fragments of the file have been recovered please? And also how may I fragment the pieces back together ? Any program to help me fragment the file? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: If the file was recoverable the software you used would do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the PST repair tool that is built into Outlook, here is a KB article from Microsoft on how to do this

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/272227

Okay next to that there must be real damage to the PST structure. Maybe trying a 3rd party tool that will try to reconstruct the file and drop off what is damaged. At this point you are at disaster recovery, something is better then nothing. The tool you are using to recover might have only got a 1% chunk of it and it's not a full file. What I normally do in these situations is I image the drive using a program that will image the entire drive. This way no matter what happens to the original disk you still have the image of the sectors of the disk. They it's a matter of running different tools to see what one can best find the files. I am assuming you did a quick format (like it took 30 for it to run) if that is the case only the first block of the sector gets turned to a omega symbol to show it can be used again. If you started to write data back to the drive again then parts of the file could be overwritten

Comment: Thanks Steve. I've tried to do so however I got the error saying that the file can't be opened.